# PHP convert string to int seems to give me 0

Tags: php, javascript

```
     <?php $sizeh = '<script type="text/javascript">
                    document.write(viewportheight);</script>'; 

     echo $sizeh;
     echo  gettype ($num);

     $num = (int) $sizeh;
     //$num = intval($sizeh);
      echo  gettype ($num);
      echo $num;

 ?>
```

This results is:

```
1083  string  integer   0
```

Why I am getting the value of zero while that zero should be 1083 ??

Comment: PHP is executed before JS. So you are casting the entire js string not its result.

Comment: How is `$sizeh` 1083?  Your PHP script cannot see the values of javascript like that.

Comment: Please learn about the basics of the [client-server model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-server_model) and consequently the distinction between server-side executed code (PHP on the webserver) and client-side executed code (Javascript in the user's browser). It's essential knowledge for a web developer.

Answer (score 2):

you're trying to change int value from $sizeh, not from $num. $sizeh is that your javascript code

Look [here](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/9b312.php)

```
    <?php 
   $sizeh = '<script type="text/javascript">
                    document.write(viewportheight);</script>'; 
     $num = "1083";
     echo $sizeh;
     echo  gettype ($num)."  ";
     echo $num."  ";
     $num = (int) $num;
     //$num = intval($sizeh);
      echo  gettype ($num)." ";
      echo $num;

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing outputs from both JavaScript and PHP. 1083 is being written by JavaScript code. string, integer and 0 are being  echoed by your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php $sizeh = '<script type="text/javascript">
                document.write(viewportheight);</script>';
```

`$sizeh` now is this ugly string. You will see 1083 in your browser because your browser run JS. But it will after php stop works

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are looking at the browser window and not at the source code: `$sizeh` is a string, starting with `<script type ...`. When you cast that string to an integer, the result is `0`.

You cannot capture the output of javascript in php as the php is processed first, then sent to the browser after which the browser executes the javascript. To send a javascript value back to php you would need to post a form or use ajax.